# Hyperlink to a text file how to open in webform?

Tags: asp.net

I have a webform and I want to create a hyperlink to a text file, so that it
opens on internet explorer in a new window.
I have added the following

```
<a href="file:///D:/Test/Test.txt" id="hplTest" runat="server">testhyperlink</a>
```

Now when I click on the hyperlink, nothing is happening. No error.
when I open a browser and type `file:///D:/Test/Test.txt`, the file is opening.

I would appreciate if anybody could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can not give physical path in href with `file://`, give the url instead.

```
<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com/Test/Test.txt" id="hplTest" runat="server">testhyperlink</a>
```

If the file is within current site then use relative path.

```
<a href="~/Test/Test.txt" id="hplTest" runat="server">testhyperlink</a>
```

The ~ here is for root path.

Comment: how to used in local machine?

Answer (score 0):

The physical path is wrong in your example.
Either you can use absolute path

```
  <a href="http://myDomain/folder/Test.txt" id="hplTest" runat="server">testhyperlink</a>
```

Or you can use the relative path

```
<a href="~/Test.txt" id="hplTest" runat="server">testhyperlink</a>
```

You can also use `target` on anchor tag if you want to open it in a new window

```
<a href="~/Test.txt" id="hplTest" runat="server"  target="_blank">testhyperlink</a>
```

More target [Detail Link of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target.aspx)